# How to assign variables to numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to make a function to generate rotational matrix R. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def R(theta):
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = -1*np.sin(theta)
    c = np.sin(theta)
    d = np.cos(theta)
    return np.matrix('a b; c d')
```

But it has error like this

```
raise TypeError("Invalid data string supplied: " + astr)
TypeError: Invalid data string supplied: a
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That matrix notation:

```
a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
```

only works for literals, not variables; with scalar variables you'd use the bracket notation

```
np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])
```

This part, `[[a, b], [c, d]]` is an ordinary Python list (of lists).  `np.matrix(...)` then takes this list and turns it into a `numpy` matrix.

But really, you should be using

```
np.array(...)
```

`np.matrix` was written to make things familiar to MATLAB visitors.  Most `numpy` work is the `array`, not `matrix`.

Another point - `a = np.cos(theta)` works with `theta` is scalar or an array.  But if an array, than `a` itself will be an array, not a scalar.  You should be aware of that when constructing this rotation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

use [.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to put the variables into string form

```
return np.matrix('{} {};{} {}'.format(a,b,c,d))
```